# Graph in R for visualizing a vector with entries 0,1 and 2

Tags: r, graph

I have never used R so this question might be simple for someone,

however I was checking the manual and documentation and still could not find a right graph so I am asking you guys.

What I have is a file containing information about another text file. The information is simple, for each position in the text file, in my result file is either a 0,1 or 2.

So what I want as a visualisation is basically just a rectangle, going from position 1 to the length of the text, and colored with 3 colors - either if it was a 0,1 or 2 in my result file.

Does someone know which visualisation graph should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a version with ggplot2:

```
# create test data
zerototwo <- data.frame(position=1:100, value=sample(0:2, 100, replace=TRUE))

# if this produces an error, do: install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(aes(x=position, y="", fill=as.factor(value)), data=zerototwo) + geom_tile()
```

Comment: Thank you.. I tried it and I managed to generate a result.. 

But as soon as my text file gets to big, R is not able any more to visualize it. Do you know how to scale in this case, or are they any other ways?

Comment: It depends. How big is it, and how does doing it this way fail? You may need to change the size of the plot

Comment: I think it might be to big..however i will find a way, maybe just show a small portion of it as an example.

One last question for you, is it possible to decrease the hight of the y- axis? 
Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: but what do you mean with changing the size of the plot??  I have like 5 million positions in the text file

Comment: `geom_tile(height=0.5)` instead.